# Metasploit wmap_run -e hangs with Using code '404' as not found

Tags: metasploit

**Background**

When I run Metasploit, it hangs at the same place no matter what I do. It stops at this line,

> [*] Using code '404' as not found.

**Steps to reproduce,**

```
msf > mfsconsole
msf > load wmap
msf > wmap_sites -l
msf > wmap_targets -t http://123.12.123.123/index.php
msf > wmap_run -t
msf > wmap_run -e
```

At this point it runs and then gets stuck here,

> [*] Using code '404' as not found.

I have tried this on MacOS High Sierra & Kali Linux.

Both fail in the exact same place.

What is the cause of this and how do I overcome it?

Comment: The only way i was able to get past this so far was to change the module `auxiliary/scanner/http/brute_dirs.rb` to `auxiliary/scanner/http/brute_dirs.rb.bak` to remove it from being ran during the scan.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My resolution was to reload the modules.

You can do that with the following command:

`wmap_modules -r`

Answer (score 1):

Get out of metasploit, and run:

```
mv /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/brute_dirs.rb /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/brute_dirs.rb.bak
```

This worked for me and is based on the comment of @rubio above.